# Overlay 'div' does not align to the correct item

Tags: html, css, alignment, overlay

Using Django, I'm passing a dictionary called listings into an HTML template. The dictionary has a key (listing), which corresponds to a specs, which is another dictionary with specific fields like 'price' or 'title'.

Then in template, I'm using a `for` loop to display all the listings with their image. I also create a 'status' overlay div (the divs with class `status`), which displays more specific information about the said listing, and appears on hover--which I am currently doing with the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` properties.

The problem is, when I have two or more items on the page, all the overlay divs appear over the first item in the page, so when I hover over the first item, I get the overlay for the last item (since they've been stacked on top of each other).
How would I make the overlay div appear over the corresponding listing?

Here's my code:
**HTML template**

```
        <div class="items-container">
        {% for listing, specs in listings.items %}
            <div class="status" id="{{ listing }}" onmouseover="showstatus(this)" onmouseout="out(this)">
                <div class="status-content">
                    <h2 class="update-title">_{{specs.title}}_</h2>
                    <h5 class="status-text">STATUS: {{specs.status}}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item">
                <img src="{{specs.pic}}" class="item-thumbnail">
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.items-container {
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-right: 45px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.list-item, .status {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 25%;
}

.status {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    opacity: 0;
    width: 23.6%;
}


.item-thumbnail {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f0f2ed;
    border: 18px solid #f0f2ed;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.status-content {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0) translateY(33%);
    margin-top: 3vh;
    padding: 6px;
    width: 99%;
    bottom: 48%;
}
```

**Javascript functions** (Not really necessary but included just in case)

```
function showstatus(object) {
    object.style.opacity = "1";
}

function out(object) {
    object.style.opacity="";
}
```

Note: I tried putting the `list-item` and `status` divs inside of another div, but that completely messed up my styling and the overlay divs still wouldn't align properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is because of  `position: absolute;` in `.status`.  Try changing it to `position: relative;`

It could also be because of `position: absolute;` in `.status-content` as well. Try simply removing that line of code in addition if the first one doesn't work.

EDIT: What you need to do is to add a container for each overlay and item together.  Set that position to `position: relative;` and then your `position: absolute;` for the overlay and items will be stacked ontop of eachother.  Please see what I did below.  I've added a div class `.inditem` over each item.

```js
function showstatus(object) {
    object.style.opacity = "1";
}

function out(object) {
    object.style.opacity="";
}
```

```css
.inditem{
  position: relative;
}

.items-container {
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-right: 45px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    position: absolute;
}

.list-item, .status {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 25%;
}

.status {
 position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    opacity: 0;
    width: 23.6%;
}


.item-thumbnail {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f0f2ed;
    border: 18px solid #f0f2ed;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
       <div class="items-container">
        <div class="inditem"> 
            <div class="status" id="OOO001" onmouseover="showstatus(this)" onmouseout="out(this)">
                <div class="status-content">
                    <h2 class="update-title">_The_Tiger_Shirt_</h2>
                    
                        
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" style="width: 100%; padding: 6px;">
                                    <h6 style="font-weight: thin; font-size: 13px; align-self: flex-end;">[Complete!]</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="status-text">STATUS: Available</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item">
                <h1 class="hidden">OOO001</h1>
                <img src="https://imgur.com/c3cv6SW.png" class="item-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inditem"> 
            <div class="status" id="FW20-H01" onmouseover="showstatus(this)" onmouseout="out(this)">
                <div class="status-content">
                    <h2 class="update-title">_Basic_Hoodie_</h2>
                    
                        
                            <div class="progress">
                                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" style="width: 50%; padding: 6px;">
                                    <h6 style="font-weight: thin; font-size: 13px; align-self: flex-end;">[Processing...]</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="status-text">STATUS: Ordering...</h3>
                        
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="list-item">
                <h1 class="hidden">FW20-H01</h1>
                <img src="https://imgur.com/nIZxLpA.png" class="item-thumbnail">
            </div>
        
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I did both things, but it displayed the a status div, then a list-item div, then another status div...and so on, instead of displaying them on top of each other

Comment: @RenaW This should be a very easy fix but I am having trouble witout seeing the actual output code. Can you make a codepen or share some HTML of the actual generated code?

Comment: Okay, I copied the page source into a gist here: https://gist.github.com/orph-c/899ee7525ce6f48f090db6b077eddd5c. Lmk if you need any additional info

Comment: @RenaW I have updated my answer. Please take a look

Comment: Okay, so that seemed to fix the alignment issue. But, the `list-item` divs now appear on top of each other, is there any way to get them side by side again? Also the images now sit on top of a footer I had on my page, and the footer isn't being automatically pushed down like it used to...Any fix to this? @John